# Redundant PoS node setup

Tags: proof-of-stake, nodes, network

This is a question regarding to computer networks and high availability with remote nodes but it relates directly to Proof-of-stake so I think this would be the place to ask instead of superuser, serverfault or stackoverflow.

My question relates to setting up an Ethereum staking node in the future. As we know staking nodes must be connected to the Ethereum network at all times and guarantee (ideally) an uptime of 100%.

Many issues were raised on this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethtrader/comments/530o38/eli5_staking_35_eth/) the main one being:

> If the computer you use for staking goes down or offline, you will be penalized by losing some of your stake. You only should go into this if you are serious about it and can afford super reliable equipment.

My solution to this issue was using redundant computers located in different places. So I would like to server A be the main one connected to Ethereum's network and connect server B to the Ethereum network (and possibly server C in case B is not online) as a replacement in case A goes offline for unforeseen circumstances.

Since Ethereum PoS software is not yet available I've been experimenting with Nxt and getting ready. But I still haven't found a reliable way to use server B in case server A is down. I am looking for a more generic unix way to use server B as a replacement.

What is a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Rocketpool platform will handle this

Comment: Hi - can you explain a little more about how this is handled by Rocketpool? I'm assuming this is a staking pool, rather than software that can be used for solo-staking on a local machine?